# Performance between C-contiguous and Fortran-contiguous array operations

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Below, I compared performance when dealing with sum operations between C-contiguous and Fortran-contiguous arrays ([C vs FORTRAN memory order](http://www.visitusers.org/index.php?title=C_vs_Fortran_memory_order)). I set `axis=0` to ensure numbers are added up column wise. I was surprised that Fortran-contiguous array is actually slower than its C counterpart. Isn't that Fortran-contiguous array has contiguous memory allocation in columns and hence is better at column-wise operation?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.standard_normal((10000, 10000))
c = np.array(a, order='C')
f = np.array(a, order='F')
```

In Jupyter notebook, run

```
%timeit c.sum(axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 84.6 ms per loop
```

```
%timeit f.sum(axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 137 ms per loop
```

Comment: you're doing this but using Python... Isn't there some emulation?

Comment: cannot verify this. For me, `b.sum(axis=0)` is 2.51s and `c.sum(axis=0)` is 0.14s

Comment: Which version of `numpy` are you using?

Comment: `np.add.reduce(x, axis=0)` shows the same behaviour, and is what `sum` does under the hood

Comment: For which the implementation begins [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/2af06c804931aae4b30bb3349bc60271b0b65381/numpy/core/src/umath/ufunc_object.c#L2973)

Answer (score 5):

I think it's in the implementation of the np.sum(). For example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.random.standard_normal((10000,10000))
C = np.array(A, order='C')
F = np.array(A, order='F')
```

Benchmarking with Ipython:

```
In [7]: %timeit C.sum(axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 101 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit C.sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 149 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit F.sum(axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 149 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit F.sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 102 ms per loop
```

So it's behaving exactly the opposite as expected. But let's try out some other function:

```
In [17]: %timeit np.amax(C, axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 173 ms per loop

In [18]: %timeit np.amax(C, axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 70.4 ms per loop

In [13]: %timeit np.amax(F,axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 72 ms per loop

In [14]: %timeit np.amax(F,axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
```

Sure, it's apples to oranges. But np.amax() works along the axis as does sum and returns a vector with one element for each row/column. And behaves as one would expect.

```
In [25]: C.strides
Out[25]: (80000, 8)

In [26]: F.strides
Out[26]: (8, 80000)
```

Tells us that the arrays are in fact packed in row-order and column-order and looping in that direction should be a lot faster. Unless for example the sum sums each row by row as it travels along the columns for providing the column sum (axis=0). But without a mean of peeking inside the .pyd I'm just speculating.

EDIT:

From percusse 's  link: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

> Reduces a‘s dimension by one, by applying ufunc along one axis.
>
> Let a.shape = (N_0, ..., N_i, ..., N_{M-1}). 
>   Then ufunc.reduce(a, axis=i)[k_0, ..,k_{i-1}, k_{i+1}, .., k_{M-1}] = the  result of iterating j over range(N_i), cumulatively applying ufunc to each
>   a[k_0, ..,k_{i-1}, j, k_{i+1}, .., k_{M-1}]

So in pseudocode, when calling F.sum(axis=0):

```
for j=cols #axis=0
    for i=rows #axis=1
        sum(j,i)=F(j,i)+sum(j-1,i)
```

So it would actually iterate over the row when calculating the column sum, slowing down considerably when in column-major order. Behaviour such as this would explain the difference.

eric's link provides us with the implementation, for somebody curious enough to go through large amounts of code for the reason.

Comment: So are you suggesting an array's type of order is not necessarily related to performance and we'd better test each case?

Comment: No, it's definitely related to performance. But yes, if you have something performance critical benchmarking yourself is a better idea than rules of thumbs, especially with black box algorithms. [link](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/optimizing/index.html) uses behaviour that we expected as an example, stating that .sum(axis=0) would be orders of magnitude slower on a large matrix. And Daniel said  in the comments that he saw such behaviour too. So it might be version dependant too. I'm running Numpy 1.11.1 with Python 3.5.2.

Comment: This is really helpful. It answers something really puzzles me for a long time...

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. If you check the result of

```
%timeit f.sum(axis=1)
```

it also gives similar result with the timing of `c`. Similarly,

```
%timeit c.sum(axis=1)
```

is slower.

---

Some explanation: suppose you have the following structure

```
|1| |6|
|2| |7|
|3| |8|
|4| |9|
|5| |10|
```

As Eric mentioned, these operations work with `reduce`. Let's say we are asking for column sum. So intuitive mechanism is not at play such that each column is accessed once, summed, and recorded. In fact it is the opposite such that each row is accessed and the function (here summing) is performed in essence similar to having two arrays `a,b` and executing

```
a += b
```

That's a very informal way of repeating what is mentioned super-cryptically in the [documentation of reduce](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html).
This requires rows to be accessed contiguously although we are performing a column sum [1,6] + [2,7] + [3,8]... Hence, the implementation direction matters depending on the operation but not the array.